# Storing email addresses anonymously

Tags: php, postgresql, hash, cryptography

I run a service where users can log in, but I will never have a need to send an email to them. I try to keep user data as anonymous a possible. I'm not interested in user tracking, selling data, etc. I know there will be simpler solutions to this question, such as "don't use email addresses in the first place" but they make a good login identifier because they are GUIDs. My service goes though the process of having the user verify the address, that's the only email I'll ever send.

So I had the idea of storing the addresses anonymously. My first thought was to simply store the SHA512 hash of each address, but in the event of a breach - which I believe my security would prevent - technically somebody could use rainbow tables to recover at least some of the addresses.

To use a salted hash, I need some way to narrow down the potential result list so I don't compute hashes for every user for every login. That won't scale. To achieve that, my idea was to store the first 5 characters of the SHA512 of the email. That wouldn't be a unique value of course, but it gives me a smaller pool of potential matches. Technically, this all works great.

My concern though is this is still vulnerable to rainbow tables. Those 5 characters are enough to look up possible inputs, and the attacker would already know that only inputs that look like email addresses would be valid. They'd still have enough to determine the email address given the first part of an unsalted hash and entire salted hash.

Am I overthinking this though? For the record, I'm using pgsql and php in this case, but that's really an implementation detail.

*Update*: I'm still not sure if I'm going to go ahead with this, but for anybody curious, the problem with rainbow tables here can be solved rather easily. Rather than hashing the whole email and taking the first few characters of the hash, use the first few characters of the email as the hash input and store the whole hash. It achieves the same effect, but at best the rainbow table will only reveal the first few characters.

Answer (score 0):

To me, I think yes. You are over-looking.
no matter how strong your structure is, there is always a small chance of breach as nobody is perfect and no can be the human made script.
I think you should go for the best  option you think it is and then stick to it.

Some things are best left to fate.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overthinking this. You stated that you don't need to email the users down the road, so my question back to you is why do you need to store the email at all? You mention that it's a good GUID, but if you're that concerned about data security, would it not be easier to let users define a username upon email verification?

Basically, I picture an ephemeral usage of the email, where it's never stored in the database, and only used to send a validation email. This would allow you to send a custom one-time-use link to the email, which would allow your user the chance to create a custom login name, which you could validate against your database to make sure it is unique.

You could then safely store this unique identifier without the concern that it would lead to email insecurity.

All of that said, I don't think any of it is necessary. As you said, email is an excellent GUID. What makes it an excellent GUID is that it is so widely known and available. The risks associated with the release of a plaintext email are far fewer and less damaging than the risks of a plaintext password. I believe our time as developers is better left securing the private data, and not the public data.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. I stuck all of it into a branch earlier so I'll still have the code. As for the "why not use a username" question, it's just to reduce the "oh hell, what was my username for this site" scenario.

Comment: @ThomMcGrath That is definitely a legitimate concern. That's generally why we use email. And when you don't have a backup like email to recover it with, you're out of luck in that scenario. I think you're fine storing email in the database. If you want to be paranoid, use a salted hash. Anyone who cracks that is going to break whatever security you put in place anyhow.